# Linux dirty page writeback behavior if write() twice to the same page

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I understand the default write() behavior (if the file is not opened using O_DIRECT or O_SYNC,etc..) on Linux is cached write -- write operations are deferred in the page cache.

Consider the below scenario:

1) a program write 1KB of data to a file at offset 5000, hence making the corresponding page a dirty page

2) the same program later write 1KB of data to the same file at the same offset, assuming the previous page is not yet flushed by pdflush, so what will the kernel do?

I imagine the Linux kernel could be doing one of the following:

a) the previous dirty page is flushed before the secondary write() can happen

b) the previous dirty page is overwritten and pdflush only flush the buffer after the secondary write() to disk

c) I could be fundamentally wrong as the second write() use a new page..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to your question is that **the previous dirty page is overwritten**.

The dirty page will be clean after a flusher thread does writeback it to backing device. But even the page is written back and not dirty anymore, it might still be in use for the same offset of the file.

On following conditions will the pages be returned to buddy system.

- The file is close. Thus, all cache pages of this file will be freed.
- [drop_caches is triggerd](http://www.linuxinsight.com/proc_sys_vm_drop_caches.html)
- Free memory is below watermark, cache pages will be reclaimed.

If you have are interested in it, I encourage you to add log in **do_generic_file_read** to verify it. The result of **page = find_get_page(mapping, index)** could show you the actual page struct address corresponding to the index of a file.

http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/mm/filemap.c#L1478

Answer (score 1):

Kernel flushing threads are started at system initialization, they are activated when there are too many dirty buffers, in cases when more buffers are needed and very little memory is available.

The dirty pages are flushed before the secondary write(), if the dirty page (write back) ratio has been exceeded in the system, which means the number of dirty pages in the memory have exceeded a certian threshold, which is vm tunable using `sysctl`, unless your application does not manually invoke a fsync() or sync() syscall.

Note: pdflush has been replaced by using flushing threads per backing device info (BDI) in the newer versions of the kernel.
pdflush - in 2.6 or older kernels
flush - in 2.6.32.

These kernel threads can be tuned from /proc/sys/vm/bdflush file:age_buffer, b_flushtime = jiffies + age_buffer

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Actually here my assumption is that the first write() is not flushed yet ( let's say the ratio is far less than the threshold and the secondary write() occurs at less than 30 seconds later after the 1st write, 30 seconds is the default value for vm.dirty_expire_centisecs).   Because in both writes we are writing to the same file from the same offset and the length is the same, I suppose they should be backed by the same page, so still the question remains, will the dirty page after the 1st write() is forced to flush before the 2nd write() can happen?

Comment: As you are not intending to use O_SYNC flag, your second write would not immediately flush to the disk, which would only trigger the flush thread when the second write to complete, based on the assumption that it has not exceeded the vm.dirty_expire_centisecs or vm.dirty_ratio parameters.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether "stable page writes" are used.

See the 2012 LWN.net article "[Optimizing stable pages](https://lwn.net/Articles/528031/)".  (The optimization was to automatically not use them if they are not needed :-).